# Parellel Task Library vs UI Thread Xamarin.Forms when constantly updating the UI

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.forms, async-await, task-parallel-library, ui-thread

I am trying to make a stopwatch in Xamarin Forms and was wondering if I should use the native UI threading or Parallel Task Lib to constantly update the time label?

I tried to use the PT Lib, but I'm unable to get it to update my label, which makes me think that I should be using Native Threading, but I'm worry if I would be able to update the UI using a dependency service.

Is there a best practice for constantly updating the UI but still being able to execute other tasks such as button clicks?

---

**UPDATE**: I got this code below to work, but is this good practice? I am updating the time label constantly while still also bing able to press the lap buttons.

```
Stopwatch sw = new StopWatch();
bool inRace = false;
async void StartLapClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{

    if (!inRace)
    {
        inRace = true;
        sw.Start();
        updateTimer();
    }
}

async void updateTimer()
{

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while(inRace)
        {

            string slc = sw.Elapsed.ToString();
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                timerLbl.Text = slc;
            });
            Task.Delay(100).Wait();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What resolution do you need on your stopwatch?  Seconds or sub-seconds?

Comment: @ctacke I will display the time in minutes:seconds.miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

No, your code has some issues (according to the [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)):

- `async void` is bad - this will call your method in fire-and-forget fashion, you even can't get the errors from there. You should use it **only** for event handlers like `StartLapClick`, not for real methods like `updateTimer`
- `Task.Delay(100).Wait();` - Do not block on tasks, use `await` for this
- replace the whole `while` loop with a simple timer, and remove the `Task.Delay` call
- `updateTimer();` - you're calling `async` method in synchronous fashion, which is also bad.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the UI from the UI thread. You could have a timer or something running in the background kicking out events periodically to be picked up and forwarded to the UI thread. Even if you did that, I don't know that the parallel task library is what you'd want to use. That's more focused on running many tasks... in parallel.

Comment: I got it to work with async and await functions. would this be best practice? I have posted the code I got to work

Comment: Yeah, that should be ok, but in general, you should avoid creating async methods that return void. For one thing, if any exception occurred inside UpdateTimer(), there would be no way to catch it.

Comment: Very great point, I had not thought about errors inside the function. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0), () => { 
    // Your code
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but my promblem wasn't starting a timer, it was updating the timer label on my xaml while still being able to click buttons.